# JSON Desrialize Dictionary

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Im trying to deserialize this json, originally the Airlines property is a IList but this doesn't work because the values are changing, so i used Dictionary  i can get the key just fine but the values are empty.

This is the Sample JSON i'm trying to deserialize

```
 "airlines": {
      "MH": {
        "lowcost": true,
        "name": "Jetstar Asia",
        "alliance_name": null,
        "id": 300,
        "rates": "18",
        "average_rate": "3.12"
      },
      "PR": {
        "lowcost": true,
        "name": "Tigerair",
        "alliance_name": null,
        "id": 800,
        "rates": "26",
        "average_rate": "3.41"
      },
      "CZ": {
        "lowcost": false,
        "name": "Singapore Airlines",
        "alliance_name": "Star Alliance",
        "id": 449,
        "rates": "620",
        "average_rate": "4.18"
      },
      "SQ": {
        "lowcost": true,
        "name": "AirAsia Zest",
        "alliance_name": null,
        "id": 839,
        "rates": "104",
        "average_rate": "2.56"
      },
      "GA": {
        "lowcost": true,
        "name": "CEBU Pacific Air",
        "alliance_name": null,
        "id": 169,
        "rates": "72",
        "average_rate": "3.44"
      },
```

This is the properties

```
[JsonProperty("airlines")]
public Dictionary<string, Airlines> Airlines { get; set; }

public class Airlines
{
    [JsonProperty("AirlineDetails")]
    public ICollection<AirlineDetails> AirlineDetails { get; set; }   
}

public class AirlineDetails
{
    [JsonProperty("average_rate")]
    public string AverageRate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("alliance_name")]
    public string AllianceName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lowcost")]
    public bool Lowcost { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("rates")]
    public string Rates { get; set; }
}
```

Picture below shows there is a count which is 5 exactly as the JSON object count above, but the values are empty, i also want to get the values which is the name of airline.

[image]

Empty Value:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Airlines` class is not necessary. Declare your property as `Dictionary<string, AirlineDetails>`:

```
public Dictionary<string, AirlineDetails> Airlines { get; set; }
```